# How to rename directory and subdirectories recursively in linux?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, directory

Let say I have 200 directories and it have variable hierarchy sub-directories, How can I rename the directory and its sub directories using mv command with find or any sort of combination?

```
for dir in ./*/; do (i=1; cd "$dir" && for dir in ./*; do printf -v dest %s_%02d "$dir" "$((i++))"; echo mv "$dir" "$dest"; done); done
```

This is for 2 level sub directory, is there more cleaner way to do it for multiple hierarchy? Any other one line command suggestions/ solutions are welcome.

Comment: Can you describe in words how you'd like to rename the directories? Also, can you add a sample directory tree to the question, with an expected final state?

Answer (score 1):

I had a specific task - to replace non-ASCII symbols and square brackets, in directories and in files as well. It works fine.

First, exactly my case, as a working example:

```
find . -depth -execdir rename -v 's/([^\x00-\x7F]+)|([\[\]]+)/\_/g' {} \;
```

or separately non-ascii and brackets:

```
find . -depth -execdir rename -v 's/[^\x00-\x7F]+/\_/g' {} \;
find . -depth -execdir rename -v 's/[\[\]]+/\_/g' {} \;
```

If we'd like to work only with directories, add `-type d` (after the `-depth` option)

Now, in more generalized view:

```
find . -depth [-type d] [-type f] -execdir rename [-v] 's/.../.../g' '{}' \;
```

Here we can control dirs/files and verbosity. Quotes around {} may be needed or not on your machine (backslash before ; serves the same, may be replaced with quotes)

Answer (score 0):

You have two options when you want to do recursive operations in files/directories:

Option 1 : Find

```
while IFS= read -r -d '' subd;do
  #do your stuff here with var $subd
done < <(find . -type d -print0)
```

In this case we use find to return only dirs using `-type d`
We can ask find to return only files using `-type f` or not to specify any type and both directories and files will be returned.

We also use find option `-print0` to force null separation of the find results and thus to ensure correct names handling in case names include special chars like spaces, etc.

Testing:

```
$ while IFS= read -r -d '' s;do echo "$s";done < <(find . -type d -print0)
.
./dir1
./dir1/sub1
./dir1/sub1/subsub1
./dir1/sub1/subsub1/subsubsub1
./dir2
./dir2/sub2
```

Option 2 : Using Bash globstar option

```
shopt -s globstar
for subd in **/ ; do
  #Do you stuff here with $subd directories
done
```

In this case , the for loop will match all subdirs under current working directory  (operation `**/`).

You can also ask bash to return both files and folders using

```
for sub in ** ;do #your commands;done
  if [[ -d "$sub" ]];then 
      #actions for folders
  elif [[ -e "$sub" ]];then
      #actions for files
  else
     #do something else
  fi
done
```

Folders Test:

```
$ shopt -s globstar
$ for i in **/ ;do echo "$i";done
dir1/
dir1/sub1/
dir1/sub1/subsub1/
dir1/sub1/subsub1/subsubsub1/
dir2/
dir2/sub2/
```

In your small script, just by enabling `shopt -s globstar` and by changing your for to `for dir in **/;do` it seems that work as you expect.

Comment: @aruns - Answer updated - Fixed some small things and include some testing. Let me know if this info is helpfull for you